# Python dice game not working as expected

Tags: python

I need some help with this code! It essentially allows the user to create two characters and enter a skill value and a strength value. It creates a modifier for each by subtracting the smallest from the largest. Two dice are rolled for each character and the highest roller gets the modifier added to his values and the lowest subtracted. Then if the strength is less than or equal to zero the character is dead. But it doesn't work, they both survive even if the strength is less than 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import random
c1 = str(input("First Character Name: "))
c1st = int(input("Strength: "))
c1sk = int(input("Skill: "))
c2 = str(input("\nSecond Character Name: "))
c2st = int(input("Strength: "))
c2sk = int(input("Skill: "))
strengthmod = max(c1st, c2st) - min(c1st, c2st)
skillmod = max(c1sk, c2sk) - min(c1sk, c2sk)
c1roll = random.randint(1,6)
c2roll = random.randint(1,6)
print('\n'+ c1 +' rolled a ' + str(c1roll))
print(c2 +' rolled a ' + str(c2roll))

if c1roll > c2roll:
    c1st = c1st + strengthmod
    c1sk = c1sk + skillmod
    c2st = c2st - strengthmod
    c2sk = c2sk - skillmod
elif c2roll > c1roll:
    c2st = c2st + strengthmod
    c2sk = c2sk + skillmod
    c1st = c1st - strengthmod
    c1sk = c1sk - skillmod

if c1st <= 0:
    if c2st <= 0:
        print(c1 + c2 +" have both died in battle")
        c1st == 0
        c2st == 0
    else:
        print(c1 + " died in combat")
        c1st == 0
elif c2st <= 0:
   print(c2 + " died in combat")
c2st == 0
   print("\nBoth had the strength to survive the fight\n")

print(c1+'s Strength is at '+str(c1st) +" and skill is " + str(c1sk))
print(c2+'s Strength is at '+str(c2st) +" and skill is " + str(c2sk))
```

Comment: I don't see why your code wouldn't work when either `c1st` or `c2st` goes to 0 or below. Your `c1st == 0` lines are not assigning 0, they are testing if the values are *equal to* 0 (then discarding the test), but those are relatively harmless and not the cause of your problems.

Comment: Your `c2st == 0` line (after the `elif`) is missing an `if` or you'll get an indentation error there for the next `print()` line.

Comment: And don't use `strengthmod = max(...) - min(...)` when `strengthmod = abs(c1st - c2st)` is much easier to write. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add an `else` to the `if/elif`. As it stands, the "both survive" line is in the same code block as "c2 died in combat", which does not make all that much sense.

Also, I think you want to use `c2st = 0` instead of `c2st == 0`, i.e. set the strength to zero in case it is below zero.

```
if c1st <= 0:
    ...
elif c2st <= 0:
    print(c2 + " died in combat")
    c2st = 0
else:
    print("\nBoth had the strength to survive the fight\n")
```